# Converting musical note Strings to MIDI pitch number

Tags: java, algorithm, midi, data-conversion

I have written the following method to convert notes (with the octave appended to the end) to the corresponding MIDI pitch:

```
// Converts a note string (MUST HAVE OCTAVE) to an integer pitch.
public static int convertToPitch(String note) {
    String sym = "";
    int oct = 0;

    String[] notes = { "C", "Db", "D", "Eb", "E", "F", "Gb", "G", "Ab", "A", "Bb", "B" };

    char[] splitNote = note.toCharArray();

    // If the length is two, then grab the symbol and number.
    // Otherwise, it must be a two-char note.
    if (splitNote.length == 2) {
        sym += splitNote[0];
        oct = splitNote[1];
    } else if (splitNote.length == 3) {
        sym += Character.toString(splitNote[0]);
        sym += Character.toString(splitNote[1]);
        oct = splitNote[2];
    }

    // Find the corresponding note in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
        if (notes[i].equals(sym)) {
            return Character.getNumericValue(oct) * 12 + i;
        }
    }

    // If nothing was found, we return -1.
    return -1;
}
```

And it works just great. However, I would also like to be able to use `convertToPitch()` with the alternate note value (Db becomes C#, etc.) for each note with an alternate name. Is there a way to do this without tearing my method apart?

Comment: Though it works, this original implementation seems far from optimized so please don't worry to tear it apart.  Setting up a `Map` to do the String to sym-integer is an improvement (which can easily adopt the `#` notes).  Unnecessary string concat is something you may want to look into too.  Imho, even better, is to determine the sym-integer by logic: e.g. switch by first note to get the "base", and add/subtract one base on 'b'/''#' to get the final number, so you can get rid of all the string concat and linear search etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
public static int convertToPitch(String note) {
  String sym = "";
  int oct = 0;
  String[][] notes = { {"C"}, {"Db", "C#"}, {"D"}, {"Eb", "D#"}, {"E"},
    {"F"}, {"Gb", "F#"}, {"G"}, {"Ab", "G#"}, {"A"}, {"Bb", "A#"}, {"B"} };

  char[] splitNote = note.toCharArray();

  // If the length is two, then grab the symbol and number.
  // Otherwise, it must be a two-char note.
  if (splitNote.length == 2) {
    sym += splitNote[0];
    oct = splitNote[1];
  } else if (splitNote.length == 3) {
    sym += Character.toString(splitNote[0]);
    sym += Character.toString(splitNote[1]);
    oct = splitNote[2];
  }

  // Find the corresponding note in the array.
  for (int i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < notes[i].length; j++) {
    if (notes[i][j].equals(sym)) {
        return Character.getNumericValue(oct) * 12 + i;
    }
  }

  // If nothing was found, we return -1.
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe begin by "normalizing" input note to expected input. I.e. initialize a string -> string map with all possible notes and normalized mappings. Should only result in some map initialization in constructor and call to map method in the beginning of convertToPitch.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the accidentals separately. So with the least modification of your code:

```
[...]
String sym = "";
int oct = 0;
int accidental = 0; // initialize with default value 0 (i.e. no accidental)

[...]

} else if (splitNote.length == 3) {
    sym += Character.toString(splitNote[0]);
    switch (splitNote[1]){
        case '#':
            accidental = 1;
            break;
        case 'b':
            accidental = -1;
            break;
        default:
            return -1; // you should really use Exceptions instead
    }
    // don't concat accidental to sym
    oct = splitNote[2];

[...]

        return Character.getNumericValue(oct) * 12 + i + accidental; // !! read the documentation of Character#getNumericValue !!
[...]
```

However, using the array index as a mapping isn't the best approach in my opinion. Depending on your input format this doesn't work since Cb is a valid note but there is no array index -1. You could create a `Map<String,Integer>` (like "C" is mapped to 0, "D" to 2, etc.) or use an [enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). You should also use [Exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html) instead of returning -1; this way you can differentiate between a malformatted string ("abbc123") and a value out of range ("B#9").

Finally, If I remember correctly, there is an offset in MIDI pitch (like C0 isn't 0 but 12).

Comment: C0 is indeed 0. C1 is 12. http://www.midimountain.com/midi/midi_note_numbers.html

Comment: This really depends on your input format. The [MIDI specification](https://www.midi.org/specifications) (which unfortunately isn't available online but see the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_Tuning_Standard)) suggests that _middle C_ is note number 60. If your input is in [scientific pitch notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_pitch_notation), then _middle C_ is C4. So if C4 is 60, then C0 is 12 and C-1 is 0. This is where you will get into trouble with your code, since the octave can be negative.

Comment: Additionally, it seems not all manufacturers comply with the scientific pitch notation; according to [this blog](http://cote.cc/blog/logic-studio-9-midi-note-numbers), _middle C_ is C3 in Logic Studio 9.

Comment: Since I can't comment on the accepted answer: You should check the input at some point because, for example, the input "Ca" will result in a return value of 120, which is a valid midi pitch but obviously not the desired output. This is because of the way [Character#getNumericalValue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(int)) works.